# Extract Data Annotations in custom ModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I’m using a custom model binder in MVC that implements System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder.

The model binder takes a generic type (class) extracts each of the class properties and stores these in a List along with additional details about each property. For example for each Property it stores access permissions i.e. Read, Write, None for each property based on the logged in user. Then in my View I use this additional data to determine whether to display a specific property or not.

I want to be able to retrieve the validation data annotations attributes for each property and store these details also. I want to store them as html attributes that I can inject into the control used to display the property later like in the example below.

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-length="Address1&#32;must&#32;be&#32;less&#32;than&#32;8!!" data-val-length-max="8" data-val-required="Address&#32;Line&#32;1&#32;is&#32;required." id="Entity_Address_AddressLine1" name="Entity.Address.AddressLine1" type="text" value="aaaa1111" />
```

Do I have to use reflection to extract the data annotation attributes from the class or is there another method? How do I output the data annotations as html attributes?

Comment: this may help ...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I dont want to create a new Validation attribute the existing ones are fine however due to the way i implement my ModelBinder they are not getting passed through to the Editor Template View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var annotations = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), false);
    foreach(var annotation in annotations)
    {
        if(annotation is RequiredAttribute)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks DZL I was looking at doing it that way but due to how I'm implementing my mvc solution this may not be applicable. I'm leaning towards using a custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider to add the annotations to the metadata for the property - not sure it will work for my implementation yet!

Comment: @gisWeeper I'd be curious of how the difference would make the answer not applicable. I'm looking at doing something similar and want to make sure I'm not missing something. Maybe you can expand your question?

Answer (score 0):

To do this I implemented a custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider (MpMetaDataProvider) which I registered and used in MVC.
You register it in the Application_Start event of the Global.asax

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MpMetaDataProvider();
```

In my MpMetaDataProvider I call the below method to return the Data Annotations for a specific property of a specific class. I hope this helps someone.

```
this.GetMetadataForProperty(modelAccessor, modelProperty.Parent.EntityType, modelProperty.Name);
```