# How to make entity framework database initialization aware of a customized variant of the required attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I've made a version of the attribute [Required], the ASP.NET MVC model data annotation which specifies that a model property and its corresponding database column cannot be null. It takes a boolean, allowing one to feed it a constant defined elsewhere.

```
public class IsRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    private readonly bool _required;

    public IsRequiredAttribute(bool required)
    {
        _required = required;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (_required == true && value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The next step is getting database initialization to work. I have not included any db init code, because until now I've completely relied on the Entity Framework's db init, e.g. DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges.

EF creates tables with columns that reject null values, for model properties with [Required], and ones that accept null for nullable properties and string properties without [Required]. I would like to have [IsRequired] mimic the presence/absence of [Required], but something is missing to make db table creation work right.

Having IsRequiredAttribute inherit from RequiredAttribute makes the db init treat [IsRequired] as if it was always [Required]. Inheriting from ValidationAttribute makes db init oblivious to it.

So, unless there is some method I've overlooked it would seem that the correct way to go about this would be to create a custom IDatabaseInitializer which is aware of the IsRequired-attribute and its boolean value.

Is that a correct conclusion?

Is the code linked below somewhat in the right direction?

[Creating Indexes via Data Annotations with Entity Framework 5.0](http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2012/08/18/creating-indexes-via-data-annotations-with-entity-framework-5-0/)

[Creating Indexes via Data Annotations with Entity Framework 5.0 (GitHub)](https://gist.github.com/dschenkelman/22a6758fdf6818b26702)

The overall purpose here is to feed the same constants for [Required], [Stringlength max/min], value ranges, etc, to both the MVC models and as client-side knockout-validation parameters, to have the models and client-side validation more closely in sync.

Comment: I don't know if it's the way im reading this... but what has the code above got to do with database initialisation? It's simply the required parameter that takes a parameter?

Comment: The db init policies shipped with MVC5 appear to be cognizant of [Required]. I think one needs to create own's own db init policy, if one were to introduce another data validation attribute of relevance to db init, which is not already known to the Microsoft-shipped policies. I'm hoping for advice on how to best go about that.

The code linked below is likely magnitudes more interesting than my own snippet.

Comment: And why exactly are you doing this? Just to see if you can?

Comment: I would like to have the same set of constants define both model properties, server-side validation and client-side validation. To not have to cross-check them manually.

Comment: I think I will turn this problem on its head, and instead of trying to inject data annotation values, rather extract them from the models, having the models and the data annotation be authoritative. Using an approach somewhat like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20097886

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Fluent API in Entity Framework Core, it is now possible do it like this:

```
public class BlogEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Blog>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Blog> builder)
    {
        builder
            .Property(b => b.Url)
            .IsRequired(MY_SHARED_BOOLEAN_CONSTANT);
    }
}
```

It meets the need I had back then when I posted the question, but I don't see myself using a boolean constant for this today, even though I'm still using integer constants for string lengths, regular expressions for validation, etc, to keep storage models and crud/command models in sync.